# wrapper to add `omp copyin` style thread safety to arbitrary data (including class members)

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, openmp

`#pragma omp parallel for copyin(blah)` is great if you need a different copy of `blah` to be created for each thread, but has some weaknesses

1. it doesn't work if `blah` is a class member variable
2. blah might be polymorphic and only some of the subclasses might need copyin semantics

Having to deal with situation #2 I came up with the following solution which seems to work but I'd like to know whether it's a good idea.

```
using namespace boost;
class OMPCopyInWrapper
{
    vector<shared_ptr<WrappedObject> > wrappedobjects;
    mutex m;
    WrappedObject& get_wrapped_object()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);
        assert(wrappedobjects.size() > 0);
        // create new objects by copying first one if needed
        while (omp_get_thread_num() >= wrappedobjects.size())
            wrappedobjects.push_back(shared_ptr<WrappedObject>(
                new WrappedObject(*wrappedobjects[0])
                ));
        return *(wrappedobjects[omp_get_thread_num()]);
    }

public:
    OMPCopyInWrapper(Blah blah)
    {
        wrappedobjects.push_back(shared_ptr<WrappedObject>(
            new WrappedObject(blah)));
    }
    forwarded_method(Foo foo)
    {
        return get_wrapped_object().method(foo);
    }
};
```

(As shown above it's specific to `WrappedObject` but the public methods could presumably be made generic following the style of `scoped_ptr` for example).

Can anyone spot problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

As nobody has answered in five days, and I've since found a serious problem with the above code, I'll post it up here.  It correctly handles OMP threads within a process (I think) but could fail when multiple processes call e.g. the same shared library.  It should be ok if each library call creates its own `OMPCopyInWrapper`.